# Can't compile pdf with latexmk when \only<handout> included / How to hide bullets in a beamer presentation

Tags: beamer, latexmk

Can someone explain why the following beamer presentation compiles with `pdflatex -interaction=nonstopmode` but not with `latexmk -pvc -pdf`:

```
    \documentclass{beamer}
    \usepackage[norsk]{babel}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    \usepackage{pgfpages}
    \setbeameroption{show notes on second screen} %show notes or show notes on second screen or hide notes

\mode<presentation>
{
  \usetheme{Frankfurt}
  \setbeamercolor{frametitle}{fg=black, bg=white!80!black}
  \setbeamercolor{item}{fg=black}
}



\title[Styrke]{Styrke}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame}
\note[itemize]
{
\item 45 min lecture
\item 20 min upto interplay between nervous system and muscle in strength development
\item 10 min on research
\item 15 min on recommendations and practical tips
}

\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Ulike typer muskelbevegelser}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item Isometrisk (statisk)
        \item Dynamisk
            \begin{itemize}
                \only<handout>{\item Konsentrisk}
                \only<handout>{\item Eksentrisk}
            \end{itemize}
        \item Isokinetisk
    \end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\note[itemize]{
\item Isometrisk (statisk)
 \begin{itemize}
     \item Spenning i muskelen uten bevegelser
 \end{itemize}
\item Dynamisk
 \begin{itemize}
     \item Konsentrisk
         \begin{itemize}
             \item Muskelen utvikler kraft mens muskellengden minke
         \end{itemize}
     \item Eksentrisk
         \begin{itemize}
             \item Muskelen utvikler kraft mens muskellengden øker
         \end{itemize}
 \end{itemize}
\item Isokinetisk
 \begin{itemize}
     \item Utvikling av kraft i muskelen under jevn hastighet
 \end{itemize}
}

\end{document}
```

It appears to have something to do with the `\only` command as putting `\visible` in its place allows it to compile with latexmk.

[EDIT] To clarify: I am trying to hide two bullet points in the slide from the presentation (`\item Konsentrisk` and `\item Eksentrisk`) but have them showing in the handout. If I use the `\visible` command it leaves a gap where the bullet points should be, which I do not want.

If I am not using`\only` correctly to do this, my question would therefore be; How can I remove bullet points from the presentation, without leaving a space and yet have them show in the handout?

Comment: It fails in both cases, `nonstopmode` just makes it run through the code without stopping. `-pvc` does not pass `nonstopmode`. `\item` cannot be enclosed like this, then `itemize` cannot see them and it complains. Perhaps `\item<handout> ...`  is what you are looking for.

Comment: `\item<handout> ...` is probably not what you are looking for, but there are methods to do what you want, see the beamer manual.

Comment: @daleif I must admit, I thought that this was what the manual recommended. Can you give me an idea what I should be looking for?

Comment: Not without knowing what exactly you are trying to do here?  Perhaps rephrase the question into something more appropriate for the situation

Comment: @daleif I have attempted to edit the question to make it clearer what I am trying to achieve. Hopefully it makes more sense now.

Comment: How about `\mode<handout>{\begin{itemize} ... \end{itemize} }` (from section 21.3 in the manual)

Comment: @daleif Ahhh! That was it. Thank you. If you write your comment as an answer then I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main issue of the question is not whether or not `latexmk` cannot compile while `pdflatex` can. Neither can due to this error:

```
\only<handout>{\item Konsentrisk}
```

Here `itemize` cannot see the `\item` and this reports an error.

From further discussions, what is really needed here is a method to only add a sublist to an item whn in **handout**. Just using `\item<handout>` does not workwell as it leaves unwanted blank space in the output.

Since this in only for handout a viable method can be to use:

```
\mode<handout>{
   \begin{itemize}
   \item Konsentrisk
   \item Eksentrisk
   \end{itemize}  
}
```